# PHP - create dynamic html table with spacer columns

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am trying to create a dynamic grid (HTML table) using php.

I need to make a table with 5 columns per row and all the odd columns will have a width of 32% whereas the even columns will be empty but have a width of 2% which is used as spacers.

I also need it so if any row doesn't have 3 odd columns, it must generate the rest to make 5 even if they are empty.

I've managed to do it so it creates 3 columns of 32% width and adds empty TDs if it needs to be I haven't been able to create the smaller 2% columns.

This is going to be used as a table grid for an HTML email

This is what I have working at the minute but only 3 columns

```
<?php 
    $test = array(1,2,3,4,5);
    $count = 0;
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.test {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
    <?php foreach($test as $t): ?>
    <?php if ($count % 3 == 0) echo "<tr>";  # new row ?>
    <td width="32%" class="test">
        <p>ddfhfdhfgh</p>
        <p>sdgdfgdgd</p>
    </td>
    <?php $count++; ?>
    <?php if ($count % 3 == 0) echo "</tr>\n";  # end row ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php if ($count % 3 != 0): ?>
    <?php while ($count++ % 3): ?>
    <td width="32%">&nbsp;</td>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and I've tried adding this but it makes a mess.

```
<?php if ($count % 3 == 0) echo "<tr>";  # new row ?>

    <?php if ( $count & 1 ): ?>
        <td width="32%" class="test">
            <p>ddfhfdhfgh</p>
            <p>sdgdfgdgd</p>
        </td>
    <?php else: ?>
        <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php $count++; ?>
```

All i need is a table with 3 large columns and 2 spacer columns in between

Comment: Why not just use css  and add padding or margin to your 3 columns?

Comment: @Alfwed Probably because this is being sent as an email and email html readers dont normally work very well with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick.

You were making it a bit more complex than it needs to be.

First you can make use of the `foreach` syntax like this `foreach ($array as $index => $value)` so you dont need to keep your own counter.

Second, you basically want every other column to take a different size so use `% 2` and not `% 3` and a simple `if then else` construct.

It also makes code easier to read if you dont use the php start and stop tags `<?php ... ?>` around every line of PHP, if you have more than one line of consecutive php code just use one to start the interpreter above the first line and one after the last line of PHP code. Otherwise it tends to Fry the brain trying to read and understand the code.

```
<?php 
    $test = array(1,2,3,4,5);
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.test {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
<?php 
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($test as $i => $t): 

        if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) :
            echo '<td width="32%" class="test">';
                echo '<p>ddfhfdhfgh</p>';
                echo '<p>sdgdfgdgd</p>';
            echo '</td>';
        else :
            echo '<td width="2%" class="test">&nbsp;</td>';
        endif;

    endforeach;

    // if array has less than the expected 5 occ add blank columns
    if ( $i < 5 ) :
        $i++;
        for ( $i ; $i < 5; $i++ ) :
            if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) :
                echo '<td width="32%" class="test">Filler</td>';
            else :
                echo '<td width="2%" class="test">&nbsp;</td>';
            endif;
        endfor;
    endif;
    echo '</tr>';
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a lot closer than I've got...thanks. The larger column with the <p> tags in it will contain data which is in the array whereas the 2% columns are just spacers. Is there a way to have a large column for each of the values in the array and add any column spacers where required?

Comment: Oh hang on yes, I forgot about the issue of the array having less that 5 occurances. Give me a few secs

Comment: There, try the amended code it should invent any missing columns now